# Production quality WPF examples

Tags: wpf, projects-and-solutions, production

As I'm learning WPF I came across quite a few examples, but mostly all of them have a disclamer like 'this is not production quality code', as they refer to a specific issue they're addressing.

What I would like is to see how is WPF used in reallife, the application as a whole, so that in one example I can see all of the best practices at work (binding, resource files, multilanguage, solution organisation, etc... from basic stuff to advanced).

Do you know of such examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I liked learning WPF on the reference implementation (StockTrader) of PRISM (CompositeWPF)
http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/
It basically has most of the goods what makes WPF so powerful and prism is a great app framework.

Comment: The compositewpf is definitely worth checking out... but it's just another framework - I was hoping for some complete examples, like that stockTrader you mentioned.

Comment: The StockTrader application is contained in Prism as an example of how to use it. I know its meant to learn Prism not WPF, but it uses Model/View seperation patterns through binding, Dependency Injection, custom controls/styling, unit tests and some more techniques that are definatly what WPF is all bout in my book. And you will hit the walls that can be overcome by the techniques discussed by for example Josh Smith (posted by Matthieu).

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer, but whoever runs into some nice examples, please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An example I would recommend is the code used in [Josh Smith article about MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). The WPF parts shows you how to deal with different aspects of the XAML syntax, and it especially shows you what you have to do behind (in the view model, in this example) to make it work. Unit tests are included in the solution, which is nice, as they are often forgotten in example projects.